# Посмотрите пожалуйста на класс для MySqli

Tags: php, ооп, классы

Здравствуй, я уже задавал вопрос по поводу класса, мне ответило много пользователей, за это им большое спасибо.
Я изучил их ответы и постарался всё сделать более правильно, я переделал этот класс и прошу посмотреть ещё раз на него и если ,я опять что-то упустил, рассказать об этом и желательно объяснить почему так нельзя делать и т.п.
Все строки подписаны, для лучше понимания.
Вот код на [github](https://github.com/iliailia1212/db/blob/master/db.class.php)
И вот он же тут:

```
<?php
Class db{
    private $mysqli;
    public function connect($cfg){//Функция подключения ,при вызове передаём настройки с данными от бд
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($cfg['bd']['host'], $cfg['bd']['user'], $cfg['bd']['password'], $cfg['bd']['name']);//подключение к бд
        if($this->mysqli->connect_errno !== 0) throw new Exception('Ошибка подключения к бд #'.$this->mysqli->connect_errno);
        $this->mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");//установка кодировки
        $this->mysqli->set_charset("utf8");//установка кодировки
    }
    public function read($table,$columns=array('*'),$filter=false,$order=false){//функция для получения данных из бд ,при вызове передаём: название таблица, [название столбцов], [дополнительный sql фильтр]
        return $this->changeToArray($this->mysqli->query('SELECT '.$this->columns($columns)." FROM `$table`".$this->filter($filter).$this->order($order)));//преобразовываем их в двух мерный массив и возращяем
    }
    public function create($table,$data){//добавления данных в бд, при вызове передаём: названия таблицы, массив вида 'название столбца'=>'данные'
        $keys = array();//тут будут хранится название столбцов
        $values = array();//тут будут хранится вносимые данные
        foreach($data as $key=>$val) {//перебор входящего массива
            $keys[] = sprintf('`%s`',$key);//добавляем новое название столбца
            $values[] = $this->safety($val);//добавляем новые данные
        }
        $this->mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `$table` (".implode(', ', $keys).') VALUES ('.implode(', ', $values).')');//добалвяем данные в БД
    }
    public function update($table, $filter, $data){//функция редактирования, при вызове передаём: названия таблицы,фильтр, массив вида 'название столбца'=>'данные'
        $chunks = array();//тут будет хранится sql запросы
        foreach($data as $key=>$val) {//переберам данные
            $chunks[] = sprintf('`%s` = %s', $key, $this->safety($val));//добавляем новые данный в sql запрос
        }
        $this->mysqli->query("UPDATE `$table` SET ".implode(', ', $chunks).$this->filter($filter));//обновляем данные в бд
    }
    public function delete($table, $filter = false){//функция удаления ,при вызове передаём: название таблицы, [фильтр]
        $this->mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `$table`".$this->filter($filter));//удаляем данные из бд
    }
    public function err(){//функция возращает ошибки
        if($this->mysqli->errno == 0) return false;
        else return $this->mysqli->error;
    }
    private function filter($data) {//Функция для генерации sql фильтра данных
        if(empty($data)) return '';//Если данные пустны, возращяем пустую строку
        $counts = count($data);//Подсчитываем количество фильтров
        $text = ' WHERE';//Создаём переменую для фильтров
        foreach($data as $name=>$el){
            $data_n = $this->configs($el,array(array(true,'name'),array(true,'data'),array(false,'='),array(false,'AND')));//Генрируем массив с данными
            $text .= " `$data_n[0]` $data_n[2] ".$this->safety($data_n[1],array('array'));//Добавляем новые данные в нужном виде
            if(--$counts) $text .= ' '.$data_n[3];//Если этот элемент не последний, то добавляем логический оператор
        }
        return $text;
    }
    private function order($data) {//Функция для генерации sql соритровки
        if(empty($data)) return '';//Если данные пустны, возращяем пустую строку
        $data_n = $this->configs($data,array(array(true,'name'),array(false,'ASC')));//Генрируем массив с данными
        return 'ORDER BY `$data_n[0]` $data_n[1]';//Возращаем данные в нужном виде
    }
    private function columns($data) {//Функция для генерации списка колонок
        $list = array();//Создаём переменую для хранения колонок
        foreach($data as $el){//Перебераем список
            $list[] = (($el == '*')?$el:sprintf('`%s`', $el));//Добавляем колонку в нужном ввиде
        }
        return implode(', ', $list);//Возращаем данные добавив запятые
    }
    private function configs($arr, $def) {//Функция для герации массива данных исходя из данных значений и стандартных
        $i = 0;
        foreach($def as $val){//Перебераем стандартные значения
            if(!isset($arr[$i])) {//Если данных нету в массиве ,добавляем их из стандартных
                if($def[$i][0]) throw new Exception('Ошибка при генерации массива настроек, обезательные данные не были переданы!');//Если эти данные обезатенльные ,то выводим ошибку
                else $arr[$i] = $def[$i][1];//Если эти данные не обезательные берём их их стандартных данных
            }
            $i++;
        }
        return $arr;
    }
    private function safety($str, $not = array()) {//Функция для форматирования данных, устранения иньекций
        if(in_array(gettype($str),$not)) return '""';//Если тип переданных данные равен запрещёным типам, то возрёщаем пустую строку
        else switch(gettype($str)) {//Определяем тип данных
            case 'boolean':
                $str = $str?1:0;//Если данные типа boolean , то возращаем 1 или 0
            break;
            case 'integer':
                $str = $str;//Если это цифра ,то так её и оставляем
            break;
            case 'string':
                $str = '"'.$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($str).'"';//Если это строка, то добавляем кавычки с двух сторон и убираем все имеющиеся кавычки
            break;
            case 'array':
                $str = $this->safety(json_encode($str));//Если это массив ,то преобразовываем его в json данные
            break;
            default:
                $str = '""';//Если данные другого типа, то возращяем пустую строку
            break;
        }
        return $str;
    }
    private function changeToArray($result) {//внутреняя функция для преобразования sql данных в двухмерный массив
        if($result===false) return array();
        $results = array();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ $results[] = $row; }
        return $results;
    }
    public function __destruct() {//функция закрытия соединения.
        if(!empty($this->mysqli)) $this->mysqli->close();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: вы же для себя делаете, чего спрашивать то. Зачем танцы с safety, когда есть prepare. Мне к примеру столько методов не нужно, удобнее запрос написать строкой. $mysqli может и в паблике пригодиться.

Answer (score 0):

Все проблемы на месте.

Возможно, где-то исправлена какая-то незначительная косметика, не играющая ровно никакой роли, но все принципиальные проблемы - такие как инъекции, производительность, читабельность, архитектура - остались прежними.

Еще размышляя над предыдущим вопросом, я задумался о том, почему у всех новичков получается практически одинаковая функция `read()`? И пришел к выводу, что это от, мягко говоря, неверных представлений об SQL.

Смотрим на функцию read:

```
read($table,$columns=array('*'),$filter=false,$order=false)
```

то есть, автор функции полагает, что у него будут (наиболее часто) встречаться запросы вида

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

которые эта функция замечательно оптимизирует.

Реальность же говорит нам о том, что такого рода запросы в серьезном приложении не встречаются ВООБЩЕ. Ну за единичными исключениями. А чаще всего встречаются запросы с сортировками, выборками и так далее. И вот если мы посмотрим на обычный запрос в синтаксисе этого квери билдера, то нам станет дурно. Очень жаль, кстати, что автор не предоставил примеры применения своей библиотеки. Одного примера, в котором условия во WHERE указываются через логическое OR хватило бы для оценки - и не нужно было бы тратить столько слов.

Не говоря уже о том, что условия, бывает, группируются скобками, обрабатываются функциями и так далее. А в SQL есть такие операторы как GROUP BY, HAVING, функции и множество других вещей которые этот класс не поддерживает.

Про джойн и вовсе промолчим )

То есть, в какой-то момент появится необходимость выполнить с его помощью обычный, чистый SQL запрос - то ли потому что класс его не поддерживает, то ли потому что трудозатраты на написание запроса  в синтаксисе класса в сотни раз превышают затраты на написание SQL. И тут выяснится, что простой запрос этот класс выполнять не умеет! Сапожник оказался без сапог. Класс для выполнения запросов не может выполнить запрос! И пользователю ничего не останется, как вернуться к старому доброму синтаксису query-while-fetch. И меня еще просят рассказать про инъекции.

В который раз я повторяю свою рекомендацию писателям классов:

- хотите облегчить **рутинные** операции с таблицами? Пишите **ORM**. Сделайте ему функции получения строки по ид и списка с лимитом. плюс создание обновление, опять же по айди. ВСЁ. Не надо замахиваться на большее.
- для всех остальных запросов - **научите свой класс нормально исполнять обычные запросы, чисты SQL!** Пользы будет больше чем от 1000 функций read.
- писать query builder стоит только после того, как ознакомился с существующими решениями и хотя бы минимально ознакомился с синтаксисом SQL.

В завершение я не могу не отметить отдельный АДЪ с чтением.
Уже не в первый раз я встречаю жертву таинственной банды рэкетиров, которые терроризируют программистов за каждую лишнюю строчку кода.

Comment: Немогли бы вы мне подсказать, где тут иньекции?